# How do you restructure a dataset before binding it to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I'm retrieving a DataSet from my database but I want to present it differently then how it is returned. I currently have rows that look like this first table, I'm showing these in a gridview.

I now want to restructure the data so that the output will be like the 2nd table. I don't always get the same "Week" so I have to check which weeks I have and iterate through them to rebuild the data. I do this by the "var result" I however do not know how to properly use the result that returns the weeks to build my gridview.

```
|------------------------------------------|
| Ansvarig | Name           | Week  | Tid  | 
|------------------------------------------| 
| John Doe | John Andersson | 4     | 29,0 |  
| John Doe | John Andersson | 5     | 0,0  | 
| John Doe | John Andersson | 5     | 0,0  | 
| John Doe | John Andersson | 13    | 8,0  | 
| John Doe | Anders Cameron | 4     | 8,0  | 
| John Doe | Anders Cameron | 12    | 11,0 | 
| John Doe | Steve Smith    | 4     | 8,0  | 
| John Doe | Steve Smith    | 6     | 0,0  | 
| John Doe | Steve Smith    | 6     | 0,0  | 
| John Doe | Steve Smith    | 7     | 0,0  | 


|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Ansvarig | Name           | Week 4  | Week 5  | Week 6  | Week 7  | Week  12 | Week  13 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| John Doe | John Andersson | 29,0    | 0,0     | 0,0     | 0,0     |          | 8,0      |
| John Doe | John Andersson | 29,0    | 0,0     | 0,0     | 0,0     |          | 8,0      |
| John Doe | Anders Cameron |  8,0    |         |         |         | 11,0     |          |
| John Doe | Steve Smith    |  8,0    |         | 0,0     | 0,0     |          |          |
| John Doe | Steve Smith    |  8,0    |         | 0,0     | 0,0     |          |          |


protected void update_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeView view = new TimeView();
    DataSet ds = view.TimeOverview(fromDatum, tomDatum, ansvarig, anvandare);



    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
    dv.Sort = "Vecka";

    var result = from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 where 1 == 1
                 group row by new { weeknumber = row["Week"] } into g
                 select new
                 {
                     weekMax = g.Max(x => x["Week"]),
                 };


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group and pivot to get the result.

1. You need a new object list or `DataTable` to store the final results
2. You need to identify the unique named pairs (Ansvarig / Name)
3. You need to dynamically add the week columns
4. You need to return the resulting `DataTable` or object list

A solution would look something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var results = GetResults(GetTestData());

        foreach(DataColumn dc in results.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write("{0},", dc.ColumnName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach(DataRow dr in results.Rows)
        {
            foreach(DataColumn dc in results.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write("{0},", dr[dc.ColumnName]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetResults(DataSet ds) 
    {
        var result = (from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              let ansvarig = row.Field<string>("Ansvarig")
              let name = row.Field<string>("Name")
              let week = row.Field<int>("Week")
              let tid = row.Field<double>("Tid")
              group row by new { ansvarig, name, week } into grp
              select new
              {
                  Ansvarig = grp.Key.ansvarig,
                  Name = grp.Key.name,
                  Week = grp.Key.week,
                  Total = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Tid"))
              }).ToList();

        var uniqueWeeks = result
                            .Select(item => new { Week = item.Week })
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Week)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ansvarig", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));

        // add week columns
        foreach(var item in uniqueWeeks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Week: {0}", item.Week);
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(string.Format("Week {0}", item.Week), typeof(System.String)));
        }

        // add rows
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var foundRow = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Ansvarig") == item.Ansvarig && r.Field<string>("Name") == item.Name);
            if (foundRow == null)
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Ansvarig"] = item.Ansvarig;
                dr["Name"] = item.Name;
                dr[string.Format("Week {0}", item.Week)] = item.Total;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                foundRow[string.Format("Week {0}", item.Week)] = item.Total;
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

    private DataSet GetTestData()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ansvarig", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Week", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tid", typeof(System.Double)));

        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "John Andersson";
        dr["Week"] = 4;
        dr["Tid"] = 29;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "John Andersson";
        dr["Week"] = 5;
        dr["Tid"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "John Andersson";
        dr["Week"] = 5;
        dr["Tid"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "John Andersson";
        dr["Week"] = 13;
        dr["Tid"] = 8;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Anders Cameron";
        dr["Week"] = 4;
        dr["Tid"] = 8;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Anders Cameron";
        dr["Week"] = 12;
        dr["Tid"] = 11;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Steve Smith";
        dr["Week"] = 4;
        dr["Tid"] = 8;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Steve Smith";
        dr["Week"] = 6;
        dr["Tid"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Steve Smith";
        dr["Week"] = 6;
        dr["Tid"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Ansvarig"] = "John Doe";
        dr["Name"] = "Steve Smith";
        dr["Week"] = 7;
        dr["Tid"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Not exactly pretty but it will output:

```
Ansvarig,Name,Week 4,Week 5,Week 6,Week 7,Week 12,Week 13,
John Doe,John Andersson,29,0,,,,8,
John Doe,Anders Cameron,8,,,,11,,
John Doe,Steve Smith,8,,0,0,,,
```

Working fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/UgpXDN

Comment: Wow did not expect such a good answer, now I just have to get this sucker to output to my gridview.:)

Comment: @Kolla I would personally try and move away from the DataSet and create a class to hold these objects. It makes the whole process easier. Then you can have a generic List<MyClass>.

Comment: Yeah I'll have to read up on it cause I'm not sure how to do it.:)

Comment: Thought I would be able to bind the dt to the grid but not getting that to work

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-DataTable-dynamically-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx